# How to use \DeclareCiteCommand, with style

Tags: biblatex

I am attempting something similar to: [Biblatex footnotes to margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227752/5834)
To the extend that I can steal their example.

What I would like to do, is have the text cited in the main text normally,
then in the side bar using the author name, then the date, then the work name.

For purposes of this MWE I am just using base latex `\marginpar`.
(In my actual work I am using Koma scrnote-layer stuff.
But that doesn't really matter as I am trying to understand BibLaTeX)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}


% bib-file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
  @BOOK{KandR,
    AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
    TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
    PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
    YEAR      = {1988},
}  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}


\newcommand{\tcite}[1]{
    \textcite{#1}
    \marginpar{
        \citeauthor{#1}, 
        \citeyear{#1}. 
        \citetitle{#1}  
    }
} 

% doc
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\tcite{Knu86}
\blindtext
\tcite{Knu86,KandR}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: MSE output]

It can be seen that the Blue circled text is perfect.
But the red cirled text is wrong, because it is collated by fields.
The reason for this is obvious of course.
My command does not process per key, it processes all the keys together.

My current command is:

```
\newcommand{\tcite}[1]{
    \textcite{#1}
    \marginpar{
        \citeauthor{#1}, 
        \citeyear{#1}. 
        \citetitle{#1}  
    }
}
```

I believe that I want to replace it with something made using BibLaTeX's `\DeclareCiteCommand`

So I took a swing at it:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\tcite}
{   % prenote
    \usebibmacro{prenote}%
}
{   %loopcode
    \printnames{author}%
    \marginpar{
        \printnames{author}, 
        \printfield{year}. 
        \printfield{title}  
    }
}
{   %sepcode
    \multicitedelim%
}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

[image: Better working]

This works, we can see both the blue circled and the red circles is fine as far as being seperate.
But I am not benifiting from the Styling of Author names (eg being abridged to last name only, based on my settings).
And since I haven't uses `\textcite` but rather just put in `printnames{author}` then I am not benefiting from any styling there either.

This is (I assume) because I have used the low level commands, for these things.
How can I use higher level commands that respect style/configuration

Answer (score 7):

You should not use high-level commands such as `\citeauthor` in a  `\DeclareCiteCommand`. It is possible to do so with `\citeauthor{\thefield{entrykey}}`, but it is not a great idea.

Instead just use the bibmacros that are used for `\citeauthor`

```
\newbibmacro{sidecite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{year}}
```

Since in your example you wanted to recreate `\textcite` of `numeric`, I went with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}


% bib-file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
@BOOK{KandR,
  AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
  TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
      YEAR      = {1988},
}  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}


\newbibmacro{sidecite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{year}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}%
   \setunit{}%
   \marginpar{\usebibmacro{sidecite}}%
   \setunit{%
     \ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
       {}%
     \textcitedelim}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% doc
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\textcite{Knu86}
\blindtext
\textcite{Knu86,KandR}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: numeric example output, cropped]

---

With `authoryear` things are easier

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}


% bib-file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
@BOOK{KandR,
  AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
  TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
      YEAR      = {1988},
}  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\newbibmacro{sidecite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{year}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\tcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \marginpar{\usebibmacro{sidecite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% doc
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\tcite{Knu86}
\blindtext
\tcite{Knu86,KandR}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: authoryear MWE]

Answer (score 0):

`\usebibmacro{<macroname>}` lets you invoke a bib-macro in a `DeclareCiteCommand`.
It doesn't, however, let you invoke something that was itself defined using `DeclareCiteCommand` so no `\usebibmacro{citeauthor}`.

So the new code could be:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\tcite}%
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}% prenote
{   %loopcode
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
    \marginpar{\usebibmacro{cite}, \printfield{title} \\
}
}
{\multicitedelim}% sepcode
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Running this, with a more interesting citation style set in biblatex:
`\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}`
gives:

[image: Fixed]

Comment: A command declared with `\DeclareCiteCommand` is not a bibmacro. You can call it simply with `\citeauthor`. In another `\DeclareCiteCommand` you'd need `\citeauthor{\thefield{entrykey}}`. But it is easier and more natural to just use the associated bibmacro: `\usebibmacro{author}`, for example.