# scrlayer-notecolumn `\makenote` with `BibLaTeX`

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, robust-commands, scrlayer-notecolumn

Continuing my journey into BibLaTeX + scrlayer-notecolumn.
I thought, [once I had the BibLaTeX working with `\marginpar` it would all be easy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379916/how-to-use-declarecitecommand-with-style).
But not so.

I want to create my sidebar using the `scrlayer-notecolumn`'s  `\makenote`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

% bib-file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
}  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\tcite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{   %loopcode
    \usebibmacro{cite}
    \makenote{\printfield{title}}
    %\marginpar{\printfield{title}}
}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
    hi
    \makenote{a side note}

    \tcite{Knu86}
\end{document}
```

---

#### \marginpar{

using the commented out `\marginpar` works fine:

[image: marginpar working demo]

---

#### \makenote{

using `\makenote` does not.

[image: not working makenote]

With errors:

`` line 35: Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
: Overwriting file `./dco2.bib'.
: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
: \clearnotecolumns while active non-layer page style.
line 35: Flush note box `marginpar'
: \pdfmdfivesum unavailable. ``

---

#### \makenote{\protect

To me this seems like maybe it was being fragile,
So I used `protect`
changing to `\makenote{\protect\printfield{title}}`

[image: protected]

Which gave me, basically the same set of errors.

```
line 35: Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
: Overwriting file `./dco2.bib'.
: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
: \clearnotecolumns while active non-layer page style.
line 35: Note moved down from(scrlayer-notecolumn) 11.0pt to 15.08002pt(scrlayer-notecolumn) at note box `marginpar'
line 35: Flush note box `marginpar'
: \pdfmdfivesum unavailable.
```

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed an expansion problem. `\makenote` writes to an auxiliary file. So write expansion will be used. But `\printfield{title}` won't be expanded to the title. And if you protect it, just `\printfield{title}` will be written to that file. This does not help, because while the read state of the auxiliary file `\printfield{title}` cannot expand to the title too.

So what you need is the title to put it into the argument of `\makenote`. The standard approach to do so would be to use `\edef\helpermacro{\printfield{title}}` or `\protected@edef\helpermacro{\printfield{title}}` and then use `\makenote{\helpermacro}`. But this wouldn't do the job too, because while using the cite command, `\printfield{title}` will expand only to `\printfield {title}`.

But there is another hook you can use, the field format of field `title`. We just can define a new field format `makenote` that uses `\makenote` to print a field and use this new format to print the field `title`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples}

\DeclareFieldFormat{makenote}{\makenote{#1}}% define new makenote field format

\DeclareCiteCommand{\tcite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{   %loopcode
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
    \printfield[makenote]{title}% use makenote format to print field title
    %\makenote{\printfield{title}}
    %\marginpar{\printfield{title}}
}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
    hi\makenote{a side note}

    Here a \verb|\tcite{knuth:ct}|: \tcite{knuth:ct}
\end{document}
```

[image: format result]

In opposite to the format you could also define a new wrapper `\mkbibmakenote` similar to `\mkbibfootnote`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples}

\newrobustcmd{\mkbibmakenote}[1]{%
  \makenote*{\blxmkmakenote{#1}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\blxmkmakenote}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@blxinit
    \blx@setsfcodes
    \blx@postpunct@agroup
    #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\tcite}[\mkbibmakenote]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{title}%
}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
    hi\makenote{a side note}

    Here a \verb|\tcite{knuth:ct}|: \tcite{knuth:ct}done.
\end{document}
```

[image: wrapper result]

If you need both, a cite print in the text and a cite print in the margin you have to define your own command, that does a `\cite` and a `\tcite`.

Comment: I have been trying to work out how I would extend this if I want to do two fields. (and worse if I want to do the names rather than just fields).
I think I am working it out, kind of.

Comment: For names you can define a name format. For multiple fields/names you can collect the fields/names and do the `\makenote` at the post code of the cite command.

Comment: How do you collect them up? that is what has been giving me trouble